# Javascript don't add the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

hello everyone javascript don't add the class to html

```
$(".ocmessage").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('p').html();
    if(strpos(text,"<b>"+name+"</b>")!==false) $(this).addClass("quoteme");
});
```

this code should detect if in `<p>...</p>` there are name of some member and if there is javascript should add class `quoteme`

how can i fix it?

Comment: what is name. should throw an error

Comment: can you please jsfiddle with html code

Comment: what is  error on console

Comment: `strpos()`? In JavaScript?

Comment: strpos ( php ) == indexOf ( javascript )

Comment: @DOC: I know what `strpos()` *is*, my question, though perhaps I wasn't clear enough, was: why is `strpos()` (a [tag:php] function) being used in JavaScript?

Comment: @DavidThomas no you were too quick with your comment, was for op

Comment: @lolfika I've added an answer. Give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this. BTW, `name` isn't defined.

```
var name = '';  // change the value
if(text.indexOf("<b>"+name+"</b>") > -1) {
   $(this).addClass("quoteme");
}
```

Comment: i don't know javascript well to change it
how it would be correct to change?

Comment: whatever you wanna search for

Comment: name is defined... and this code don't help me
class not added yet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ocmessage is a div or another contain class.

Take a look at : http://jsfiddle.net/40vv7dbk/

```
 $(".ocmessage").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.find('p').html();

    var name = "Ben"
    // Will be -1 if not found.
    if (text.indexOf(name) > -1) {
        $this.addClass("quoteme");
    }
});
```

What it is doing, is when the document is ready, going through all the Divs with the class ocmessage, looking for a

tag, and then checking if a name is in there. If it does, I add the class quoteme.

Answer (score 0):

Your elements with class `ocmessage` may contain more than one paragraph. So inside the first `each`-loop we have to do a second loop through all `<p>` like so:

```
$(".ocmessage").each(function(){
    var $T = $(this);
    $T.find('p').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        // find username and prevent multiple class adding
        if(text.indexOf("<b>"+name+"</b>") > -1) {
            $T.addClass("quoteme"); return false; // stop loop when class is added
        }
    });
});
```

Working [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/v8dtkpph/14/). Credits to **Amit Joki**.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very poor way to accomplish the task. Here's the more standard jquery way to do it.

```
$(".ocmessage").has('p b:contains('+name+')').addClass("quoteme");
```